# React Typescript Absolute Import "Module not found"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've read through several guides and can't seem to find the correct combination to get the app to run. I am not seeing any errors in my vs code IDE, but the following error is showing:

[image]

./tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["/*/index", "/*"],
      "@src/*": ["src/*/index", "src/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": [".github", "build", "coverage", "node_modules"]
}
```

./src/App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Login } from '@src/views';

function App() {
  return (
      <Login />
  );
}

export default App;
```

./src/views/Login.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

// interface Props {}

export default function Login(): JSX.Element {
  return <div>Login</div>;
}
```

./src/views/index.ts

```
export { default as Login } from './Login';
```

And here is my folder/file structure:

[image]

Comment: Maybe try making your path alias array strings relative, i.e. `"./src/*"` instead of `"src/*"`